We added to a circuit in the house, now half the house has no power
My husband spliced into an existing circuit, at a ceiling light fixture, in the attic to add a receptacle. My daughter plugged in space heater, and now half the house has no power. We checked all the bus fuses and none of them are blown. No breakers are tripped. But we can't get power back on in the house. What can we do?

Probably should call an electrician.  Please note where you are in the world.

Are you sure that this isn't your utility's fault?

Not enough information to help.  Assuming a smaller size house and by half you mean bedrooms, a live and/or neutral wire not connected/broken will stop power from going past it.  Turn off the breaker/s and recheck the the connections worked on before.  Pictures might help also.

Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We can only make guesses with the vague information you've provided. I'd expect a detailed description of the new connections (or a clear photo).

The first thing that a utility will tell you to do is to check the breakers by turning them all the way off and then on again.  By all the way off, I mean push until they stop being spongy and are at the actual travel limit.
When a breaker trips, it often goes into a sort of halfway state.  It can't be turned on from that state.  If you try, it will move into what looks like the on position but not let power through.  You need to turn it all the way off and then on.
Next, reset any GFCI outlets.  It's possible to use a single GFCI outlet to protect an entire circuit.  This is cheaper than a GFCI breaker.  However, if it trips, you have to reset it at the outlet.
With older houses, it's not strange to have half the outlets on one circuit and the remainder on another circuit or spread across several.  This dates back to fuse boxes that only had a few fuses.  When the fuse box was replaced with a breaker box, they didn't rewire the circuits.  Over time, they'll put in dedicated circuits for bathrooms and kitchens, but they'll leave the original circuits for the other places.
With these kinds of houses, it's better to add new circuits than splice into existing ones.  There tends to be lots of room in the panel.
A space heater is generally 1500 watts.  That's basically the entirety of a 15 amp circuit derated to 80%.  I.e. a space heater should always be on its own circuit.  Given the timeline, the heater tripping the breaker is the most likely problem.  That said, it's not impossible that there was another problem where something finally gave up the ghost at the same time.
Anyway, if resetting circuit breakers and GFCI doesn't help, the next step is a professional electrician.  You may be able to get the utility to send out a free electrician to verify that you're getting power correctly at the meter.  If they won't or if you are getting power, the next step is to get a regular electrician to troubleshoot the house wiring.  That electrician can let you know what your next step should be.

The ceiling fan circuit is a low amp circuit the space heater needs far more amps to operate
Need an electrian to size the amount of amps needed to operate the space heater and check for damage in the ceiling fan circuit, something is open or tripped if half the house is not working , sounds like one of the main bteakers is tripped
Please have a experienced electrian check the conductors ,connections and proper breaker sizing for your requirements

Please revise to properly capitalize and punctuate your sentences. Also, your opening statement is false in North America.
